# input type="number" works wrong in firefox

Tags: html, css, forms, firefox, numbers

I'm using an input type="number" in my html and it looks great in Chrome (v66), but no with Firefox (v60). Here are the results:

Using Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

---

Using Mozilla Firefox:

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

---

How could I fix it with Firefox?

Thanks!

Comment: These are vendor-specific stylings. The only way you can do something about it is to create wrappers around the widgets and style them yourself. Bootstrap, jQueryUI, Material Design, and many other styling libraries do this for consistency across browsers

Comment: I might also add that "works wrong" is not synonymous with "looks great in chrome, but not with firefox" working vs visually appealing are two different things

Comment: @mhodges , how could I do it to make them look equal? (or as equal as possible)

Comment: Style them yourself or use a style library like the ones listed above. Relying on the browser's styling for native elements is subject to differences and changes as the browser changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox have pre-built visual variations on the user-forms (and some other things as well).

Best way to avoid this from happening is to simply style your own unified looks using css. For example:

```
input[type="number"] {
   // whatever style you want, i'll go with basic box as an example
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 50px;
   height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: To add to this, even custom styles don't apply sometimes.  For instance, for a while Firefox went back and forth as to wether they allowed select controls to have custom arrows or not.  There were hacks to try to get the arrow to disappear but between different versions, sometimes they worked and sometimes they didn't.

Your best bet for consistency is to either use a custom control completely or do your best to make it work the way you want and know that the browser can still override it if/when they want to.